# Set Different port in Fail2Ban for Linux AMI?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, fail2ban

I am using EC2 Instance, Linux AMI currently and have shifted the Default SSH Port 22 to a Higher TCP Port (Let's say 1234) , currently i am able to do easy login using -p 1234 Parameter while connecting to SSH over a Terminal.

I have Installed `Fail2Ban` on AMI Instance, and I have created a file called `jail.local` , Now i see the content like this

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
maxretry = 6
```

Now, here i Think There is a `port = ssh`, Now is this port=ssh would probably point to Default 22 Port but that i had already changed to 1234, So shall my configuration include `port = ssh, 1234` or `port = 1234` or any Other than that?

One more question is Amazon EC2 AMI Instance has no /var/log/auth.log currently, when i use `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log` It gives `No such File or Directory` But `/var/log/secure` is present and gives me Log Outputs.

So do i also need to change `logpath` too? 
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're on the right path.  Only one way to find out....make the change and test :)

fail2ban monitors failed logins by the specified log.  So if you see them in /var/log/secure than my guess would be point there.

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = 1234
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/secure
maxretry = 6
maxretry = 6
```

Additionally if you wanted to monitor more than the specific port here is an example below:

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = 1234,sftp,ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/secure
maxretry = 6
maxretry = 6
```